# ¿Cómo juntar dos o más matrices en una nueva matriz concatenando las filas?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo una matriz `A` y una `B`:

```
A = [["maría", "21"],
     ["Juan", "20"], 
     ["Diego", "21"]]

B = [["1 mascota", "gato"], 
     ["2 mascotas", "gato y perro"], 
     ["1 mascota", "perro"]]
```

¿De qué forma podría juntar las matrices `A` y `B`, fila por fila, y guardarlas en la matriz `C`, es decir `C = [A + B]`?

Para que quede la matriz `C` de esta forma:

```
C = [["maría", "21", "1 mascota", "gato"], 
     ["Juan", "20", "2 mascotas", "gato y perro"], 
     ["Diego", "21", "1 mascota", "perro"]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) y aprovechar que la suma(`+`) de 2 listas es la concatenación de ambas:

```
A = [["maría", "21"],
     ["Juan", "20"], 
     ["Diego", "21"]]

B = [["1 mascota", "gato"], 
     ["2 mascotas", "gato y perro"], 
     ["1 mascota", "perro"]]

C = [a+b for a, b in zip(A, B)]

print(C)
```

Salida:

```
[['maría', '21', '1 mascota', 'gato'], ['Juan', '20', '2 mascotas', 'gato y perro'], ['Diego', '21', '1 mascota', 'perro']]
```